# select data daily using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

I have a table `tbl_worklog` with columns id (int), project_id (int), start_time (datetime), total (time), user_id (id).

I have also another table `tbl_projects` with columns id (int), project_name  (text), organization_id(int). The project_id in the first table is have a foreign key to the id in the second table.

I have also the `organization` table with column created_by (int). The id in organization table have a foreign key to the organization_id in the second table.

So here is the problem, I want to get members of all the projects that is under the organizations that created_by = 1. And in each members, I want to get their work in the first table daily. For example,

```
Members | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Weekly Total
---------------
John | 0:30:00 | 0:30:00 | 0:30:00 | 0:30:00 | 0:30:00 | 0:30:00 | 1:00:00 | 4:00:00
```

I used the start_time in the first table to be able to compute their daily work.

Here is my query that is not working,

```
SELECT (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND start_time >= '2016-09-04' AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as weekly_total,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND start_time >= '2016-09-04' AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as sun,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND start_time >= date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as mon,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND start_time >= date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as tue,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND start_time >= date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as wed,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND start_time >= date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as thu,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND start_time >= date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as fri,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total))) AS total_time from tbl_worklog WHERE start_time < date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND start_time >= date_add('2016-09-04', INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND user_id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as sat,
(SELECT name FROM tbl_accounts WHERE id=tbl_worklog.user_id) as name FROM tbl_worklog WHERE project_id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_projects WHERE organization_id=1)
```

Is there also any other way to make it simple and better practice? 
How can I do it using PDO?

Comment: Yes. You mention PHP, so handle the display issues there. Far more flexible, and scalable (although scale is admittedly less of an issue in this instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not use `group by` which is the most important here to get expected result. Try the following query to get daily result. You can modify to get it weekly result view in PHP.

```
select project_name, user_id, sum(time_to_sec(time)) as user_time, date(start_time) as 
daily_time , tw.project_id pID 
inner join tbl_projects tp on tp.id = tw.project_id 
inner join organization og on og.id = tp.organization_id 
where og.created_by = 1 group by user_id, pID, daily_time
```

Comment: So this is my entire query? How can I get Sunday work hours of that member?

Comment: did you run the query and see the output? it will give the rows as days and users. You can get the rows as column for every 7 days with some php logic